# SQL select a specify column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a Table with 3 Columns: PrimaryKey, "German" and "Englisch".
There are translations.

Now, I want to transfer the value of the specific column.

If there is language "German", then it schould select column "German.
Conversely, if this language "English", then of course, column "English".

So I want to choose the right column depending on the language mapping.

Table:

```
-----------+--------+---------
|PrimaryKey|German  | English|
-----------+--------+---------
|1         | Haus   | house  |
-----------+--------+---------
|2         | Garten | garden |
-----------+--------+---------
|3         | Apfel  | apple  |
-----------+--------+---------
```

Customer GERMAN chouse PK=2, so he gets "`Garten`".
Customer ENGLISH chouse PK=1, so he gets "`house`".

Thx

Comment: you need customer table so that you could filter by customer

Answer (score 1):

add customer table

```
    customerId  Name
       1        English 
       2        German
```

--add fk_constraint customer-customerid

```
 SELECT 

  case when customer = 1 then t.English else t.German end as [Language]
  --or 
  case when c.Name = 'English' then t.English else t.German end as [Language]

  FROM translations as t
  INNER JOIN customer as c on c.customerID =  t.customer
```

Comment: My issue in more detail here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402128/sql-select-a-specify-language-column
I hope somebody could help me.

Comment: not perfect, look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402128/sql-select-a-specify-language-column

Comment: Nobody can help me :-(

Answer (score 0):

Select colName1, colName2
   From tableName

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding OP's question. He's not interested in a result set with all German and English entries in it. He wants to select conditionally.